# Replace dan to and not daniel

Tags: r, regex, string, gsub

`name <- "DANIAL DAN AMIN"`
`gsub("DAN", "AND", name)`
The result will be like this
`[1] ANDIAL AND AMIN`

I want the result like this
`[1] DANIAL AND AMIN`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add word boundaries (`\\b`) to it and then use `gsub`

```
gsub("\\bDAN\\b", "AND", name)
#[1] "DANIAL AND AMIN"
```